# boost::geometry::read_wkt alternative?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I am trying to check if a point is inside a polygon or not. For this purpose I want to use boost library. My question is how I can modify the example from boost so that instead of reading points by read_wkt, read them from std vector.

here is the sample code from boost:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>


int main()
{
    typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> point_type;
    typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<point_type> polygon_type;

    polygon_type poly;
    boost::geometry::read_wkt(
        "POLYGON((2 1.3,2.4 1.7,2.8 1.8,3.4 1.2,3.7 1.6,3.4 2,4.1 3,5.3 2.6,5.4 1.2,4.9 0.8,2.9 0.7,2 1.3)"
            "(4.0 2.0, 4.2 1.4, 4.8 1.9, 4.4 2.2, 4.0 2.0))", poly);

    point_type p(4, 1);

    std::cout << "within: " << (boost::geometry::within(p, poly) ? "yes" : "no") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and here is my vecPoints:

```
struct PNTS{
int x;
int y;
}
std::vector<PNTS> vecPoints;
```

**please NOTE**: My question is **NOT** related to the point in polygon algorithm.

Comment: Why not iterate over your vector and build the WKT string? Would that work?

Comment: Not working, I guess...

Comment: @AnasAlkhatib added this approach as my second answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to add your vector member inside a polygon in boost:

```
using boost::geometry::append;
using boost::geometry::make;
using boost::geometry::correct;
std::vector<PNTS>::iterator iter;
for(iter = vecPoints.begin(); iter != vecPoints.end(); iter++)
{
  PNTS ver = *iter;
  append( poly, make<boost2dPoint>(ver.x, ver.y) );
}
// you have to close polygon by inserting first element as the last again
PNTS last = vecPoints[vecPoints.size()-1];
append( poly, make<boost2dPoint>(last.x, last.y) );
// you can also correct the polygon orientation
correct(poly);
```

Comment: how can it work fine, he's appending the last point twice, at the end..

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about Geometry concepts. However, this looks like it should be close, or at least give you some inspiration on how to do things.

**Update** added serialization *to* WKT so we can confirm that the polyon is identical.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb8a6d5510c83492)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/io/io.hpp>

int main()
{
    typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> point_type;
    typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<point_type> polygon_type;

    polygon_type poly;
    poly.outer().assign({
        point_type {     2,   1.3   },
        point_type {   2.4,   1.7   },
        point_type {   2.8,   1.8   },
        point_type {   3.4,   1.2   },
        point_type {   3.7,   1.6   },
        point_type {   3.4,     2   },
        point_type {   4.1,     3   },
        point_type {   5.3,   2.6   },
        point_type {   5.4,   1.2   },
        point_type {   4.9,   0.8   },
        point_type {   2.9,   0.7   },
        point_type {     2,   1.3   },
    });

    poly.inners().emplace_back();
    poly.inners().back().assign({
        {   4.0,   2.0   },
        {   4.2,   1.4   },
        {   4.8,   1.9   },
        {   4.4,   2.2   },
        {   4.0,   2.0   },
    });

    point_type p(4, 1);

    std::cout << "within: " << (boost::geometry::within(p, poly) ? "yes" : "no") << std::endl;

    std::cout << boost::geometry::wkt(poly) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
within: yes
POLYGON((2 1.3,2.4 1.7,2.8 1.8,3.4 1.2,3.7 1.6,3.4 2,4.1 3,5.3 2.6,5.4 1.2,4.9 0.8,2.9 0.7,2 1.3),(4 2,4.2 1.4,4.8 1.9,4.4 2.2,4 2))
```

Comment: thanks, there is an error I am facing using boost 1.56: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::geometry::model::ring<boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double>, true, true, std::vector, std::allocator>::assign(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’

Comment: Oh well. Apparent your compiler is a bit c++11 challenged then. For convenience I'd initialize from a temporary vector by iterator range: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8901103/ (Coliru is down for the moment)

Answer (score 2):

In case, like the commenter said, you think it's easier to create the WKT from the vectors manually, here's one way to do it, in ~2 lines of code, without using anything from Boost Geometry:

```
using namespace boost::spirit::karma;
std::cout << format_delimited("POLYGON(" << *('(' << auto_%',' << ')') << ")\n", ' ', rings);
```

Full demo **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62391396fb763e1b)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/boost_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>

int main()
{
    using Ring = std::vector<boost::tuple<double,double>>;

    std::vector<Ring> rings = {
        {   {   2, 1.3 }, { 2.4, 1.7 }, { 2.8, 1.8 }, { 3.4, 1.2 },
            { 3.7, 1.6 }, { 3.4,   2 }, { 4.1,   3 }, { 5.3, 2.6 },
            { 5.4, 1.2 }, { 4.9, 0.8 }, { 2.9, 0.7 }, {   2, 1.3 },
        },
        {   { 4.0, 2.0 }, { 4.2, 1.4 }, { 4.8, 1.9 }, { 4.4, 2.2 }, { 4.0, 2.0   },
        }
    };

    using namespace boost::spirit::karma;
    std::cout << format_delimited("POLYGON(" << *('(' << auto_%',' << ')') << ")\n", ' ', rings);
}
```

Prints:

> `POLYGON( ( 2.0 1.3 , 2.4 1.7 , 2.8 1.8 , 3.4 1.2 , 3.7 1.6 , 3.4 2.0 , 4.1 3.0 , 5.3 2.6 , 5.4 1.2 , 4.9 0.8 , 2.9 0.7 , 2.0 1.3 ) ( 4.0 2.0 , 4.2 1.4 , 4.8 1.9 , 4.4 2.2 , 4.0 2.0 ) )`